# reference coordinates after rotate with magick++

Tags: imagemagick, magick++

I am writing a C++ program that rotates an image a defined amount of degrees and then needs to crop a specific area of the rotated image.
However I have noticed that the coordinate system changes after rotation and have not been able to find documentation stating how it changes.

(i.e. if after rotation I crop an area starting at 0,0, the resulting image is from an area lower and to the right)

So far I have noticed that it rotates around the center and if the width is larger by n, then x starts at -n/2.
What happens if width was reduced? i.e. if a rectangular image was rotated 90 degrees?

Is there an easy way to get it? or documented somewhere?

Thank you

Comment: Using ImageMagick from the command line, adding "+repage" just after the rotation will reset the page geometry so "0,0" is the upper left corner.

Comment: This is all basic [trigonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry). You would be responsible for tracking the coordinate as it translates through rotation, and updated `Geometry` offsets accordingly. Without seeing the original & expected image, or the source-code, we can't offer much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou.

This is a client-server with the client being a canvas in a web browser where there have taken place trigonometric calculations to find rotation angles and selection of an area to crop.

In the client, the rotation is done around the upper-left corner of the canvas.
Confirmation about my asumption that imageMagick rotates around the center of the image in an imaginary plane would have been enough.

I decided to go the repage route as it saves time and avoids posible future complications if apis were to change.
iMagick++ has such Method in its Image class.